# React Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop of type `Object` supplied

Tags: reactjs, eslint, react-props, react-proptypes, eslint-config-airbnb

I am getting the warning "Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop  of type `Object` supplied to , expected instance of `bound checkType`."

This is my proptypes:

```
FieldTable.propTypes = {
    rawData: PropTypes.instanceOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    percentCols: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.string).isRequired,
    specialColNames: PropTypes.instanceOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired,
    scenarioHeaders: PropTypes.instanceOf(PropTypes.object),
    headerHierarchies: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.object).isRequired
};
```

What is this 'bound checkType' it is referring to and how should I be validating my object props to avoid this warning?  The objects themselves are JSON objects received from asynchronous calls, and generated in other components.The rawData object, for example, comes from a component that lets the user upload an excel spreadsheet then parses the spreadsheet into a JSON object.  Don't know if that's useful information or not.

Thanks for any assistance and especially any deeper discussions that may arise from this question.

Comment: I should add that I am under string eslint rules so I cannot use simple `PropTypes.object.isRequired` since that will trigger the react/forbid-prop-types rule.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For object when `react/forbid-prop-types` eslint is enabled, try to use shapes:

```
plainObj: PropTypes.shape({ subProp: PropTypes.string })
```

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

To check proptypes of plain JS objects you should use just:

```
plainObj: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will not pass my company's eslint rule of react/forbid-prop-types so this is not a good solution for my case